# How does boost::variant allow string constants?

Tags: c++, boost-variant, typelist

So I've been playing around with typelists and boy are they interesting. One of things I wanted to do was attempt to implement my own `variant` class simply as an experiment in education on how typelists work and how they can be useful. Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <typeinfo>

#ifndef VARIANT_H_
#define VARIANT_H_

struct NullType {};

template <class T, class U>
struct TypeList {
    typedef T Head;
    typedef U Tail;
};

#define TYPELIST_1(T1)                                 TypeList<T1, NullType> 
#define TYPELIST_2(T1, T2)                             TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_1(T2) > 
#define TYPELIST_3(T1, T2, T3)                         TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_2(T2, T3) > 
#define TYPELIST_4(T1, T2, T3, T4)                     TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_3(T2, T3, T4) > 
#define TYPELIST_5(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)                 TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_4(T2, T3, T4, T5) > 
#define TYPELIST_6(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)             TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_5(T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) >
#define TYPELIST_7(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)         TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_6(T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) > 
#define TYPELIST_8(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)     TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_7(T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) > 
#define TYPELIST_9(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9) TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_8(T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9) >

namespace util {

    namespace {
        template <class TL>                 struct MaxSize;
        template <class TL>                 struct Length;
        template <class TL, class T>        struct IndexOf;
        template <class TL, unsigned int i> struct TypeAt;

        template <>
        struct MaxSize<NullType> {
            static const size_t value = 0;
        };

        template <class Head, class Tail>
        struct MaxSize<TypeList<Head, Tail> > {
            static const size_t value = (sizeof(Head) > MaxSize<Tail>::value) ? sizeof(Head) : MaxSize<Tail>::value;
        };

        template <>
        struct Length<NullType> {
            enum { value = 0 };
        };

        template <class Head, class Tail>
        struct Length<TypeList<Head, Tail> > {
            enum { value = 1 + Length<Tail>::value };
        };

        template <class T>
        struct IndexOf<NullType, T> {
            enum { value = -1 };
        };

        template <class Tail, class T>
        struct IndexOf<TypeList<T, Tail>, T> {
            enum { value = 0 };
        };

        template <class Head, class Tail, class T>
        struct IndexOf<TypeList<Head, Tail>, T> {
            enum { value = (IndexOf<Tail, T>::value == -1) ? -1 : 1 + IndexOf<Tail, T>::value };
        };

        template <class Head, class Tail>
        struct TypeAt<TypeList<Head, Tail>, 0> {
            typedef Head type;
        };

        template <class Head, class Tail, unsigned int i>
        struct TypeAt<TypeList<Head, Tail>, i> {
            typedef typename TypeAt<Tail, i - 1>::type type;
        };
    }

    template <class TL>
    class variant;

    template<class U, class TL> 
    U *get(variant<TL> *v);

    template<class U, class TL> 
    const U *get(const variant<TL> *v);

    template<class U, class TL> 
    U &get(variant<TL> &v);

    template<class U, class TL> 
    const U &get(const variant<TL> &v);

    // this stuff is a visitation pattern used to make sure
    // that contained objects get properly destroyed
    namespace {
        template <class TL>
        struct apply_visitor;

        struct destroy_visitor {
            template <class T>
            void operator()(T *p) {
                p->~T();
            }
        };

        template <class H, class T>
        struct visitor_impl {
            template <class U, class Pred>
            static void visit(U *p, Pred pred) {
                if(H *x = get<H>(p)) {
                    pred(x);
                } else {
                    apply_visitor<T>::visit(p, pred);
                }
            }
        };

        template <class H>
        struct visitor_impl<H, NullType> {
            template <class U, class Pred>
            static void visit(U *p, Pred pred) {
                if(H *x = get<H>(p)) {
                    pred(x);
                } else {
                    throw std::bad_cast();
                }
            }
        };

        template <class TL>
        struct apply_visitor {
            typedef typename TL::Head H;
            typedef typename TL::Tail T;

            template <class U, class Pred>
            static void visit(U *p, Pred pred) {
                visitor_impl<H, T>::visit(p, pred);
            }
        };
    }

    template <class TL>
    class variant {
        template<class U, class X> friend U *get(variant<X> *v);
        template<class U, class X> friend const U *get(const variant<X> *v);
        template<class U, class X> friend U &get(variant<X> &v);
        template<class U, class X> friend const U &get(const variant<X> &v);

    public :            
        variant() : type_index_(0){
            new (&storage_) typename TypeAt<TL, 0>::type();
        }

        ~variant() {
            apply_visitor<TL>::visit(this, destroy_visitor());
        }

        template <class T>
        variant(const T &x) : type_index_(IndexOf<TL, T>::value) {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;
            new (&storage_) value_type(x);
        }

        template <class T>
        variant(T &x) : type_index_(IndexOf<TL, T>::value) {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;
            new (&storage_) value_type(x);
        }

        template <class T>
        variant &operator=(const T &rhs) {
            variant(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

        variant &operator=(const variant &rhs) {
            variant(rhs).swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }

    public:
        void swap(variant &other) {
            using std::swap;
            swap(storage_, other.storage_);
            swap(type_index_, other.type_index_);
        }

    private:
        template <class T>
        const T &get_ref() const {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;

            if(IndexOf<TL, T>::value != type_index_) {
                throw std::bad_cast();
            }

            return *reinterpret_cast<const value_type *>(&storage_);
        }

        template <class T>
        T &get_ref() {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;

            if(IndexOf<TL, T>::value != type_index_) {
                throw std::bad_cast();
            }

            return *reinterpret_cast<value_type *>(&storage_);
        }

        template <class T>
        const T *get_ptr() const {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;

            if(IndexOf<TL, T>::value != type_index_) {
                return 0;
            }

            return reinterpret_cast<const value_type *>(&storage_);
        }

        template <class T>
        T *get_ptr() {
            typedef typename TypeAt<TL, IndexOf<TL, T>::value>::type value_type;

            if(IndexOf<TL, T>::value != type_index_) {
                return 0;
            }

            return reinterpret_cast<value_type *>(&storage_);
        }

    public:
        int which() const {
            return type_index_;
        }

        bool empty() const {
            return false;
        }

        const std::type_info &type() const;

    private:
        struct { unsigned char buffer_[MaxSize<TL>::value]; } storage_;
        int                                                   type_index_;
    };

    // accessors
    template<class U, class TL> 
    U *get(variant<TL> *v) {
        return v->template get_ptr<U>();
    }

    template<class U, class TL> 
    const U *get(const variant<TL> *v) {
        return v->template get_ptr<U>();
    }

    template<class U, class TL> 
    U &get(variant<TL> &v) {
        return v.template get_ref<U>();
    }

    template<class U, class TL> 
    const U &get(const variant<TL> &v) {
        return v.template get_ref<U>();
    }
}

#endif
```

And this works very well! I can write things like the following and it works great:

```
typedef util::variant<TYPELIST_3(std::string, int, double)> variant;
variant x = std::string("hello world");
variant y = 10;
variant z = 123.45;

std::cout << util::get<std::string>(x) << std::endl;
std::cout << util::get<int>(y) << std::endl;
std::cout << util::get<double>(z) << std::endl;
```

And all works as expected :-). Here's my question. With `boost::variant` I can write the following with no issues:

```
boost::variant<int, std::string> v = "hello world";
```

With my version, if I write similarly:

```
util::variant<TYPELIST_2(int, std::string)> v = "hello world";
```

I get an error like this:

```
variant.hpp: In instantiation of 'util::<unnamed>::TypeAt<TypeList<std::basic_string<char>, NullType>, 4294967294u>':
variant.hpp:76:47:   instantiated from 'util::<unnamed>::TypeAt<TypeList<int, TypeList<std::basic_string<char>, NullType> >, 4294967295u>'
variant.hpp:161:61:   instantiated from 'util::variant<TL>::variant(const T&) [with T = char [12], TL = TypeList<int, TypeList<std::basic_string<char>, NullType> >]'
test.cc:27:50:   instantiated from here
variant.hpp:76:47: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct util::<unnamed>::TypeAt<NullType, 4294967293u>'
variant.hpp:32:46: error: declaration of 'struct util::<unnamed>::TypeAt<NullType, 4294967293u>'
```

Essentially, it can't find `char[12]` in the typelist in variant. Which makes sense since `char[12]` is in fact not explicitly listed as one of the types...

**How does `boost::variant` make this work so seamlessly?** I feel like it is the only real missing piece in my understanding of how `boost::variant` works. Thoughts?

Comment: Btw, any reason why the destructor is `virtual`?

Comment: A force of habit at the unecessary cost of `sizeof(void*)` per instance of your class and extra confusion for however reads your code.

Comment: Variant is fascinating! Digging around `variant/variant.hpp`, I see that the templated constructor calls `convert_construct()`, whose type-legitimate version applies a `convert_copy_into` visitor on the internal storage address.

Comment: @Andreas Magnusson: removed `virtual` as it genuinely served no purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do is_convertible as another answer suggested. You would basically be reimplementing the C++ conversion mechanism using C++ type traits. Instead, you can use the C++ infrastructure that you already have.

The way boost does it is by having a class with a function that takes every type that the variant can accept. I'm not sure how boost does it exactly with C++03, but in C++11 syntax:

```
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
class constructor : public constructor<Rest...>
{
  using constructor<Rest...>::construct;

  static void
  construct(variant& v, First&& value);
};
```

Then your operator= and other functions call `constructor<Types...>::construct(*this, value)` and if there is an unambiguous conversion then C++ finds it for you.

I wrote a rather detailed blog post dissecting  how all this works: http://thenewcpp.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/variadic-templates-part-3-or-how-i-wrote-a-variant-class/

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of type traits like [`is_convertible`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_convertible.html) (or the C++11 stdlib version).

As @Andreas' comment says, you need to amend your templated constructor / assignment operator a bit, as in, don't search for a specific type, but for the first match.

```
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp>

template<class T, class TList>
struct FirstMatch;

template<class T, class Head, class Tail>
struct FirstMatch<T, TypeList<Head, Tail>>{
  static bool const is_conv = boost::is_convertible<T, Head>::value;
  typedef typename boost::mpl::if_c<is_conv, Head,
      typename FirstMatch<T, Tail>::type>::type type;
};

template<class T>
struct FirstMatch<T, NullType>{
  typedef struct ERROR_no_convertible_type_found type;
};

template<class T, class TList>
struct FirstOrExactMatch{
  static int const idx = IndexOf<TList, T>::value;
  typedef typename boost::mpl::if_c<idx != -1,
      TypeAt<TList, idx>,
      FirstMatch<T, TList>
      >::type::type type;
};
```

The code is untested, but should work (minus typos).

Comment: Any thoughts on how to actually apply that though? While the type's certainly do need to be convertible, I'm not sure where that would fit in to the code.

Comment: I would probably go for an `IndexOfBestMatch` meta-function that would be called when `IndexOf` fails in your ctor/`operator=`. Not sure of how `boost::variant` does it but that would mean the least change to your code as it is today.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson: interesting, I'll have to look into that. I'd love to see an answer which goes into a bit more detail that I can accept ;).

Comment: @Xeo: I would still go with first looking for an exact match and only if none is found look for an convertible match. Consider the case of `variant<TYPELIST_2(double, int)> v = 1;`

Comment: @EvanTeran: Hint taken :), but Xeo has worked so hard for this and also I'm way too tired to write meta-code...

Comment: Done now, was just glue-code between `FirstMatch` and `IndexOf`/`TypeAt`. This walks the typelist thrice, but I'm willing to improve that if requested.